# Creating realistic procedural material

Tags: materials, procedural

G'day, guys!
I really need your help here! I wanted to create the material similar to the Lotus image. But how to do it and where to start - I have now idea (I'm pretty weak in materials, just know the basics).
Thank you very much for your time and help!

Serge

[image]

Comment: What have you already tried and what results have you got? What particular part of this are you stuck with? Try Googling something like "blender marble material tutorial" and see what you can find.

Comment: G'day, Rich! I looked online for marble and found similar material called "jade". So, I experimented with it and added decals. It looks a bit odd, but more acceptable than before. :) Thanx for your hint, mate!

Answer (score 7):

Before even jumping into the node editor, identify the different components you will need for your shader. The first thing to notice is that the surface is completely diffuse. There are no subsurface or glossy components visible. The color consists of a bright yellow and a darker reddish/orangy color. The parts that are facing upwards are paler, weathered by rain and sun. You can get this gradient by using the *Dot* output of a *Normal* node. Adjust the contrast of the output with a *ColorRamp* and use it to mix between the base color and the secondary color.

[image: Image 1]

The dirt that settles in the crevices can be achieved using the *Pointiness* output with very high contrast. Use this to multiply the color with black to darken the crevices.

[image: Image 2]

In order to randomize the color in hue, value and saturation, you will need a *Noise Texture*. In this case, I split it up into R, G, and B to work with different patterns without using multiple noise textures. The combined RGB of the noise is also fed into a *Bump* node to give the surface more roughness.

[image: Image 3]

This would be the base for your shader, the work isn't done here! Now you can start to bring in realism by combining many different noise patterns, by varying the bump and by introducing more inaccuracies in color and roughness using the same simple steps as shown above.

[image]

Comment: OMG! Yann... I have no words..really... How is it possible to learn those bloody nodes in the way to get desirable results??? I've been using Blender for few years already, and still can not understand most of this node setup....
Could you tell me the proper procedure, how to learn the topic?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a procedural node setup that should get you started (in Cycles).

Using the Principled BSDF:

1. Make sure you put Subsurface to 1
2. in the Subsurface Radius, change them all to .05 (in the pic I accidentally put .5, but .05 is correct)
3. Using the mixRGB nodes choose the colors you want, then use a noise/voronoi texture to have it mix the colors, I use a color ramp in between to better control the fall off.
4. I added some slight bump with the normal map
5. I used a noise/color ramp and plugged it into the roughness map so it wasn't so glossy everywhere. 
   [image]

[image]

Comment: ooh, man! You are another Master of the Node Setup! :) Thanx a lot! Now I have something to study at least this weekend! How did you learn all of this stuff???

Comment: I have been using Blender for a couple of years, I just studied other users set ups like this https://www.artstation.com/artwork/KdDxx I learn a lot that way. I can create most materials but when I see some node set ups from @richsedman and others I am baffled how they did that. The math equation setups confuse me the most.

Comment: Oh, man! Thanx for the link! I was studying that and my head almost exploded! :) This materials node editor is the most difficult stuff for me to understand! :D